# What should be put in the bill table?

Tags: database-design

i'm doing a database project about hospital management, but im not sure what should be put in the bill table.
s[image]hould i put in it the room charge, doctor charge, medicine charge, or every one of those should be put in their respectable tables(room,doctor, medicine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but im not sure what should be put in the bill table. should i put in it the room charge, doctor charge, medicine charge, or every one of those should be put in their respectable tables(room,doctor, medicine)?

Each table represents the object they are named after and the columns in those tables should be attributes about that object. So a `doctor_charge` for example would not describe a `doctor`. Especially even more so, because the same `doctor` can see multiple `patients`, and depending on the procedures, could have different `charges`, so it wouldn't be possible to store multiple different `doctor_charges` for the same `doctor` in the `doctor` table.

Instead they should go on the `bill` or even further normalized, I believe you probably need a table like `bill_items` (or `bill_charges` if you prefer the name) to itemize each individual charge that's specifically associated with a single `bill` for a given `patient`. Not all charges will always apply to all `bills`, and there are some things that only apply to the `bill` once (and likely should live in the `bill` table) while there can be multiple `charges` that apply to the same `bill`, therefore needing to live in the `bill_items` table.

This is called [relational cardinality](https://vertabelo.com/blog/cardinality-in-data-modeling/) and it's important to be thinking about this concept when creating and relating your tables. Note this article doesn't cover every facet of cardinality, especially across the different contexts the term applies to with databases, but it's a good basic introduction.